# Analytical expression and fourier trasform of this graphically given function (in terms of rect, triang, sinc, Sa)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, step-function

I came across a strange problem

[image: Strange problem]

The first question asks me to find the fourier transform of $g(t)$, but it is given graphically so I need first to find the correct analytic expression, which is some sort of combination of $rect, triang, sinc, Sa$ and all the functions used in Signal's theory. In the interval $[-T, 0]$, the teacher suggests to consider the inclined part of the signal as the integral of a determined function (I later found out it must be the integral of a rect). The teacher also added that I should (???) remove the step function in order to get it correctly.

Can you please explain to me how I should find the Fourier transform, comprehensively? Thanks.

Comment: I think that if you can translate your question in English more people will be able to help you.

Comment: For $[-T,0]$ you have a rect function plus the integral of a rect function. For $[0,T]$ you have just a rect function. Since the FT is linear, you can find the FT of each individually and then add them together.